# Infinity new equilateral triangles in one configuration of triangle plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

An equilateral triangle constructed from a reference triangle is a topic which is intersested by plane geometry lovers. See [Napoleon equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem), [Morley equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem)....In this topic I propose more than 3000 equilateral triangles.

Consider $ABC$ be a triangle, $B_a$, $C_a$ be two points lie on $BC$, $C_b, A_b$ 
be two point lie on $CA$; $A_c, B_c$ be two points on the  $AB$ such that
$AB_aC_a$, $BC_bA_b$, $CA_cB_c$ be three equilateral triangle. Let $n$ be a
 positive integer number.

[image]

Let $A'$=triangle center $n$-th of $\triangle AA_bA_c$; $B'$=triangle center $n$-th of $\triangle BC_bA_b$; $C'$=triangle center $n$-th of $\triangle CC_aB_a$.

Let $A''$=triangle center $n$-th of $\triangle AB_cC_b$; $B''$=triangle center $n$-th of $\triangle BC_aA_c$; $C''$=triangle center $n$-th of $\triangle CA_cC_a$.

You can see define triangle center $n$-th in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KimberlingCenter.html)

[image]

[image]

**Problem:**

1. *For any positive integer $n$, any triangle $ABC$ then $A'B'C'$ be an equilateral triangle*
2. *For any positive integer $n$, any triangle $ABC$ then $A''B''C''$ be an equilateral triangle.*
3. *Triangles $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ are perspective; $ABC$ and $A''B''C''$ are perspective*

> > **My question:** I am looking for a proof of the problem above. You can check the conjecture above hold true for $n=1,\cdots ,3000$ in [here the geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/a5hpss6j)

Some new equilateral triangles I discovered recently in here:

- [SOME NEW EQUILATERAL TRIANGLES IN A PLANE GEOMETRY](http://geometry-math-journal.ro/pdf/Volume7-Issue2/5.pdf)
- [Some Equilateral Triangles Perspective
  to the Reference Triangle ABC](http://www.journal-1.eu/2018/Dao-Perspective-Triangles.pdf)

Comment: This is a weird conjecture.  If I understand it correctly, the parameterisation is really dependent on a list of known triangle centres, not on integers.  Therefore, if true now, it could become false if Professor Kimberling updates his list.  (Also, your title says 30000 but your post says 3000.)

Comment: Because, now geogebra help construct triangle center n-th (for n=1 to 3000). I want say that the conjecture true for any triangle center n-th

Comment: Yes, but my point is that there is (so far as I know) no definition  of "triangle centre" other than "one of the entries on Professor Kimberling's list", so that the truth of this conjecture could change over time (besides which it is hard to imagine anything but an exhausting case-by-case proof, given the multitude of ways that centres are defined).

Comment: I will edit again